# How to calculate the intersection of the 2 different circle's area

Tags: geometry, circles, area

I have two different circles with their formulas, which intersect from different parts of themselves, how can I calculate the area of the intersection and the rest of the circles? Is there some way to do it without using calculus? And how to calculate that area, why? Here is the question, if you find a way, it doesn't matter the exact numbers:

[image: question image]

Comment: Solution [here](https://diego.assencio.com/?index=8d6ca3d82151bad815f78addf9b5c1c6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find the intersections (I will assume that you have two points)
2. From the coordinates of the intersections and the radii of the two circles you calculate the angle between the radii corresponding to the intersection points. So, for the purple circle, the angle between $(-\sqrt{12},0), (0,0), (\sqrt{12},0)$, and for the blue circle between $(-\sqrt{12},0), (0,2), (\sqrt{12},0)$. The sine of half of the angle is equal to the ratio between half the distance between the intersection points and the radius.
3. Calculate the area of the circular sectors defined by the line between the intersections https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment#Arc_length_and_area

Comment: "The cosine of half of the angle is equal to half the distance between the intersection points and the radius." which rule is this, I didn't understand where does it come from. Also, I didn't get how we get the angle, can you please explain

Comment: Small mistake, it's sine not cosine. I'll fix the answer. Take for example the upper circle, and look at the triangle formed by the radii from the center to the two intersections. This is an isosceles triangle (radii are equal), so the bisector of the angle at the center is also a perpendicular median. Let's call $A$ and $B$ the two intersections, $O$ the center of the upper circle, and $M$ the middle of $AB$. Then $\angle AOM=\frac12\angle AOB$, $\triangle AOM$ is a right angle triangle, so $\sin\angle AOM=\frac{AM}{AO}$